# JNA: how to tell if you are on Win32 versus Win64?

Tags: jna

I'm creating a type mapping for a data type which is 'long' on Win32 and 'int64' on Win64. How do I discover which I'm running on so as to pass the correct value to the IntegerValue constructor?

I want to know if the JVM is running as a 32-bit or 64-bit application.

Comment: Do you want to find out if the OS itself is 32bit vs 64bit, or do you want to find out if your app is compiled as 32bit vs 64bit?

Answer (score 1):

JNA provides [`Platform.is64Bit()`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/Platform.java#L172).

You can define your own type based on `IntegerType` which chooses its size based on the currently-running architecture.

```
class MyInteger extends IntegerType {
    private static final boolean is64Bit = Platform.is64Bit();
    public MyInteger() {
        this(0);
    }
    public MyInteger(long value) {
        super(is64Bit ? 8 : Native.LONG_SIZE, value);
    }
}
```